# Searching string from one file and checking it in the other file in perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I have two file File1.txt, File2.txt. Searching string from one file and checking it in the other file.
File 1:

```
  <p>Texas, Florida, New York</p>
  <p>Cambridge, Oxford, Liverpool</p>
```

File 2:

```
 <p>UK Cities: Cambridge, Oxford, Liverpool</p>
 <p>test content</p>
 <p>test content</p>
 <p>US States: Texas, Florida, New York, California</p>
```

I tried with the below code, it doesn't work. Any help much appreciated.

```
open fhr, "<file1.txt";
my @line;
@line = <fhr>;
my $content;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#line; $i++)
{
  if ($line[$i]=~m/<p>(.*)<\/p>/)
  {
    $content = $1;
    open fhr1, "<file2.txt";
    my @array;
    @array = <fhr1>;
    for (my $k=0; $k<=$#array; $k++)
    {
      if ($array[$k]=~m/<p>(.[^:]*): $content<\/p>/)
      {
        print "Yes the search content present in file2";
      }
      else
      {
        print "No search content in file2";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

A few things before we start.

- The more `perl-ish` way to iterate over an array would be: `for my $thing (@things) {`. Not `for (my $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {`
- Start iterating over your file line by line as in my example below over `my @array = <FH>;`, which reads the entire file into memory.
- Always `use strict; use warnings;`
- Check out some other [`modules`](https://metacpan.org/search?q=html+parse) if you're going to be parsing HTML

Example -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = array_from_file("file1.txt");
my $file2 = array_from_file("file2.txt");

for my $str1 (@$file1) {
    print "matched $str1\n" 
        if grep { /$str1/ } @$file2;
}

sub array_from_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    my @array;

    open my $fh, "<", $filename or die $!;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($wanted) = $line =~ /<p>(.*)<\/p>/;

        push @array, $wanted;
    }
    close $fh;

    # return array ref
    return \@array;
}
```

Comment: Its working great, but I would also like to grep the content before the matched string like "UK Cities:", "US States:". Is it wrong to Checking searched content line by line using for loop?

Comment: @Senthil - You can add more strings to `grep` no problem. It is best to use a `while` loop to iterate over files as in my example. A `for` loop reads the entire file into memory before iterating over each line.